# Nested JSTL Tags

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I want to use a formatDate tag inside a param tag.  This doesn't work:

```
<fmt:message key="entry">
   <fmt:param value="<fmt:formatDate value='${entry.time}' pattern='h:mm' />"/>
</fmt:message>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the body content of `fmt:param`

Like this:

```
<fmt:message key="entry">
  <fmt:param><fmt:formatDate value='${entry.time}' pattern='h:mm' /></fmt:param>
</fmt:message>
```

This should do what you want. :)